# My custom slide doesnt go in a row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Please take a look at this
http://jsfiddle.net/CztkH/6/

I want to run my slide in a row (like how we play films). But i cant make it slide in a row :(. Please help me Q.Q
Here is my javascript that run the slide:

```
function doDoubleSlide(obj1, obj2){
    obj1.hide("slide", {direction:"left"},1000);
    obj2.show("slide", {direction:"right"},1000);
    setTimeout(function(){doDoubleSlide(obj2,obj1);}, 3000);
}
doDoubleSlide($("#sl01"), $("#sl02"));
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 11 questions and 0 accepted answers. Not a good stat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've structured your slider with JavaScript and CSS has a few different problems, I don't think there's any easy fix for what you're putting together here.

- you're animating the slides in a way that's problematic from a CSS point of view - the should be floated inline
- and you should be animating one main container  rather than animating the elements inside of their separate containers.

The best advice I could give you is to use a different approach.

I see you're using the **jQuery UI** library for the animations - I don't think that's the best fit for what you're trying to achieve here - those plugins are better suited to effects and require more work to adapt and re-skin.

There's lots of better suited, existing plugins out there specifically for slideshows like this and work well out of the box:

http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: Well, it became a mess after my working around. I though about plugs-in, like some you gave me there. There're a lot of plugs-in but i will bookmark what you gave me as recommendations. Thanks a lot. By the way, i got what i need in the beginning by modifying some line at the stylesheet. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/CztkH/10/